# ¿como podria navegar a traves de mis archivos html usando un boton no <a src> con jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

El problema surgió cuando decidí no usar la etiqueta a con href=... por razones netamente funcionales, en su defecto, debo utilizar: button id = 'btn_ingresar', el cual tendrá que ser invocado con jQuery con el evento "click" a otra página (Ej.: registros.html)

El punto es que usando un boton normal, me direccione a otro html.

EJEMPLO:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#btn_ingresar").click(function(){
  //ABRIR OTRO HTML EN LA MISMA PESTANIA Y QUE SE PUEDA           
        //VOLVER ATRAS
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que es esto lo que buscas? Redireccion a google.com por ejemplo

```
var url = "http://www.google.com"; // Aca cargo la pagina a la que quiero redirigir en una variable llamada ``url``


$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#boton").click(function(){
       $(location).attr('href',url);
    });
});
```

Comment: gracias ya habia usado este metodo y no me funcionaba y la razon era por que el boton no devia estar dentro de mi formulario es por eso ue no me lo permitia lo saque y funciono correctamente error mio gracias